# Rails and mysql. Any way to view tables?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have just started out on rails and I've been using the mysql2 gem with it.
I realised that on rails, migrations are used to alter tables in the database.

So I was just wondering if there was anyway I could view the tables in Mysql?
And also some way to make insertions, deletions etc more efficient?

Comment: Rails has a lot of smart people working on making the insertions, deletions, etc work. Any reason you want to go outside of the Rails framework? I'm all for learning more about MySQL and interacting with it manually, but if you're going to use Rails, use the stuff it gives you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your rails directory, you can use the shell command `rails dbconsole` to connect directly to the database using your rails project's configuration, and write raw SQL in the shell.

Comment: There are also many GUI clients available. http://www.sequelpro.com/ is a good one if you're on a mac.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the mysql client to interact with mysql databases. I would start by reading the documentation at mysql.